# How to add label tag in Google Sheets Query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to add a label to each of the columns generated by this query on a Google Sheets spreadsheet (see screenshot). However, when adding the label tag I get a parse error.

This is my attempt:

```
=query('6. Calendario 2022'!$C3:$E,"select E label E 'Col1' label C 'Col2', count (C) where C='Junio' and E is not null group by E")
```

Where does the label tag have to be added? What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: What's the parse error you get?

Comment: It says "Formula parse error". I think it's just the position of the tag that's not correct. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: label goes at the end of the query string.  after "group by E"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing 3rd parameter of Query (number of headers).
Also labels should be at the end of your formula:

Also when you use aggregation (like count(C) ), you should use the same form when defining a label.

```
=query('6. Calendario 2022'!$C3:$E,"select E , count (C) where C='Junio' and E is not null group by E label E 'Col1', count(C) 'Col2'")
```

Comment: This did the trick. I wasn't sure about the syntax, thanks for the explanation.